# android programmatic layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a simple two-column list in android, and need to populate the number of rows dynamically. The xml layout works fine, but when i try to build the layout programmatically the second column doesn't show. Any ideas?

```
private void addRow(String text, String value) {
    RelativeLayout line = new RelativeLayout(this);

    line.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    line.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 15);

    TextView caption = new TextView(this);
    caption.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    caption.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 30);
    caption.setText(text);

    rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    TextView val = new TextView(this);
    val.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    val.setTextColor(0x05b4e4);
    val.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 30);
    val.setText(value);

    line.addView(caption);
    line.addView(val);

    mLayout.addView(line);
}
```

The comparable xml for a single row (that works) is this

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="15px" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:text="What"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtClubPath"
            android:textColor="#05b4e4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:text="stuff"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Again - the rows populate, but the second column isn't visible. Here's what it's going into:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:id="@+id/scrollViewRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewRoot"
    android:paddingTop="20px"
    android:paddingBottom="40px"
    android:paddingLeft="20px"
    android:paddingRight="20px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The layout params of the view you are adding should be of type LinearLayout.LayoutParams because the parent will be of that type.

This line

```
line.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

should become

```
line.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

---

However, I think this should cause an exception if anything.

Comment: You're right that's what it should be. Unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is important for the RelativeLayout children to have a unique non-zero id.

You could, on API 17+, use

```
myView.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

Or if you have to support older API levels, you could use (and increment each time) a simple static AtomicInteger value.

Comment: No effect. Tried an AtomicInteger set to `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000`, but no effect.